Runs Test for a single individual
I understand the issue around inability to generalize to a population, but in this case I am interested in whether the data indicates randomness of performance in a single individual. Specifically, I am trying to assess limb laterality in a dog. If I assume, that true lateralization would be manifested as a lack of randomness in limb use when manipulating an object, could I use the Runs test on the R/L limb use in a single animal?

This site itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda35d.htm uses an example of a single coin. I see no reason why your idea for using the Runs test would be wrong. Apart from whether this test's null and alternative hypothesis are the ones you need, but you will have thought that through.
